# I'm pretty new to programming still and wanted to write my first piece of code from scratch. Could someone tell me why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, loops

This is my code and I'm wondering why it doesn't just keep printing things in the console. I'm using codecademy if that helps

```
let loopVariable = loopFunction

function loopFunction() {
  loopFunction2
  return console.log('Function')
}

function loopFunction2() {
  loopFunction
  returnconsole.log('This is looping')
}

if (loopVariable === loopFunction) {
  loopFunction
  return console.log('Let the loop commence!')
}
```

Comment: you are not correctly calling functions, you are returning console.log, console.log prints the string in console it does not return a value, you are also comparing variable to function, that's not right.  Furthermore, if everything is fixed, your code will run into Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you're not actually calling the functions inside the function.

```
function loopFunction2() {

loopFunction()
```

and

```
function loopFunction() {

loopFunction2()
```

would call the function. The parentheses invoke the function when not part of its declaration. You'd need to call loopFunction with a parentheses inside the if block as well

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now my console if just maxed out and won't run it. Thanks for the help though

Comment: And that's why infinite loops are dangerous

Comment: @JackTheRipper — "now (your) console is just maxed" ... loopFunction calls loopFunction2 which calls loopFunction which calls loopFunction2 which calls loopFunction which calls loopFunction2 which calls loopFunction which calls loopFunction2 ... do you see where that is going?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (loopVariable === loopFunction) {
loopFunction()
console.log('Let the loop commence!')
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**I DON'T KNOW WHY** but I assume you want to write some code that goes in a loop like this:

```js
        let loopVariable = loopFunction
        
        function loopFunction() {
         console.log('Function')
         loopFunction2()
          
        }
        
        function loopFunction2() {
          console.log('This is looping')
          loopFunction()
          
        }
        
        if (loopVariable === loopFunction) {
          console.log('Let the loop commence!')
          loopFunction()
          
        }
```

But this is not good for your memory! You are in a loop!

So you need to use **function nameOfTheFunction(param){...}** for declare it.

And **nameOfTheFunction(param1)** for call it

And u cannot return a console.log()!

BUT IF YOU WANT TO GO IN LOOP THE FOLLOWING IS THE BEST WAY!

```js
function a() {
  console.log('A')
}
function b() {
  console.log('B')
}
function c() {
  console.log('B')
}

while(true) {
  a();
  b();
  c();
}

// DON'T RUN THIS CODE!!!
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I ran it in codecademy to see what would happen and the website froze

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, there are a few things you should know.

First when you are calling a function, you need to add () at the end of the function name. So, you are calling "loopFunction" instead of loopFunction().

Then, you have something like this.

```
let loopVariable = loopFunction

function loopFunction() {
  loopFunction2()
  return console.log('Function')
}

function loopFunction2() {
  loopFunction()
  return console.log('This is looping')
}

if (loopVariable === loopFunction) {
  loopFunction
  return console.log('Let the loop commence!')
}
```

However, this would lead us to a stackoverflow recursion (funny, isn't it ?). I am not pretty sure what are you trying to do, but I if you want to get rid of the recursion you could write something like this.

```
let loopVariable = loopFunction

function loopFunction() {
  loopFunction2()
  return console.log('Function')
}

function loopFunction2() {
  return console.log('This is looping')
}

if (loopVariable === loopFunction) {
  console.log('Let the loop commence!')
  return loopFunction()
}
```

So, the result would be:

```
Let the loop commence!
This is looping
Function
```

What I change is to add the propper brackets, remove the call in the loopFunction2 because it will make a call in the loopFunction and this function will also call the loopFunction2 Infinite recursion). And last, I change the order in the if statement. First I print the message and then I call the loopFunction